# Radiobutton checked has changed WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, radio-button

In my WPF application i have:

-> TextBox (textChanged)

-> 2 radio buttons

-> ListView with content. "Author","Title".

I need to allow searching from Listview.

My question is: How i should check if radiobutton check is changed?

Comment: WPF/UWP is designed with teh MVVM pattern in mind. In that pattern the ViewModel has a boolean property, that is only represented (and bound to) the checkbox. Any actuall operation would be done in code behind.  If you want ot learn the MVVM pattern, here is some information to start you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: You can bind a `Command` to the radio button the same as a button or many other controls. Are you familiar with MVVM or are you just using code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments MVVM is prefered for WPF then you would bind to the IsChecked Property.

```
private bool _RadioButtonChecked;
public bool RadioButtonChecked
{
    get => _RadioButtonChecked;
    set
    {
        _RadioButtonChecked = value;
        //Refresh filter here
    }
}
```

Xaml binding:

```
<RadioButton Content="RadioButton" IsChecked="{Binding RadioButtonChecked}"/>
```

Aside from that there is are [Checked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.Checked);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) and [UnChecked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.unchecked?view=netframework-4.7.2) events that you can use.

Comment: being honest with you i don't know how i should use these code. How connnect c# code with Refresh filter?